# Linq to XML - Check for null element while parsing for DateTime

Tags: c#, .net, linq-to-xml

Let's say I have the following XML:

```
<Account>
        <AccountExpirationDate>6/1/2009</AccountExpirationDate>
</Account>
```

I want to use LINQ to XML to parse this into an object I'll call Account:

```
public class Account {
    public DateTime? AccountExpirationDate { get; set; }
}
```

This is the C# code I've tried, but it won't let me use null:

```
var accountSettings = 
  from settings in templateXML.Descendants("Account")
  select new Account {
      AccountExpirationDate =   
         string.IsNullOrEmpty(settings.Element("AccountExpirationDate").Value) 
         ? DateTime.Parse(settings.Element("AccountExpirationDate").Value) 
         : null
  };
```

Is there a way for me to only assign AccountExpiration a date if the element exists in the XML? In my business logic it is acceptable for the value to be null. Thanks!

Comment: @Mehrdad - Thanks for the format fix, it was ugly before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var accountSettings =
  from settings in templateXML.Descendants("Account")
  select new Account {
    AccountExpirationDate = 
      string.IsNullOrEmpty((string)settings.Element("AccountExpirationDate")) 
            ? (DateTime?)null
            : DateTime.Parse(settings.Element("AccountExpirationDate").Value) 
  };
```

Comment: This throws an exception when the AccountExpirationDate element is empty: System.FormatException: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime

Comment: @Andy May: you said about the element existing or not... you didn't say about it being empty...

Comment: Andy: Updated the answer. Your original snippet didn't use `string.IsNullOrEmpty` correctly and I had blindly copied and pasted that. We should return `null` if the method returns `true` not the other way around.

Comment: @Marc Gravell: He had posted a code snippet. This requirement can be inferred from it.

Comment: Well, maybe... but if we knew the code was perfectly implementing his intentions, it probably wouldn't be here?

Comment: @Marc: lol. Indeed. But we can sometimes assume it's *partially describing* intentions.

Comment: @Mehrdad - This worked! I had my logic inverted for the ?: conditional operation. Thanks for the help! @Marc Gravell: yeah, I can see how my requirements were stated clearly, thank you for your assistance as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can just use:

```
from settings in templateXML.Descendants("Account")
let el = settings.Element("AccountExpirationDate")
let el2 = (el == null || string.IsNullOrEmpty(el.Value)) ? null : el
select new Account {
    AccountExpirationDate = (DateTime?)el2
};
```

there is a conversion operator that works this magic using standard xml datetime formatting, and which returns null if the element doesn't exist (note I don't read `.Value`).

Comment: This will throw an exception if the element exists but is empty.

Comment: (fixed, but that wasn't a requirement in the original question)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
var accountSettings = from settings in templateXML.Descendants("Account")
                  where settings.Element("AccountExpriationDate") != null
                  && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(settings.Element("AccountExpriationDate").Value)
                  select new Account 
                  {
                      AccountExpirationDate = DateTime.Parse(settings.Element("AccountExpirationDate").Value)
                  };
```

Answer (score 0):

For a more readable syntax and if you need such a check multiple times, you could use extension methods:

```
public static DateTime? ToDateTime(this Element e)
    {
        if (e == null)
            return null;

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(e.Value))
            return null;
        else
            return DateTime.Parse(e.Value);
    }
```